# Failed to build active scheme

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

My `SwiftUI` project won't build anymore. It tells me `Failed to build active scheme` without any more information.
[image]

Here's the full repository:
https://github.com/nathfreder/HackerNews/tree/master/HackerNews

I noticed the issue after changing

```
ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
    NavigationButton(destination: Text("")) {
        StoryRow()
    }
}
```

to

```
ForEach(store.stories) { story in
    NavigationButton(destination: Text("")) {
        StoryRow(story: story)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the class/struct that you use for `store.stories` conform to the `Identifiable` protocol?

Comment: @MatteoPacini Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, this project includes Firebase swift package for some reason and that's causing the preview build to fail. The actual error in Xcode's Report navigator is "'GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h' file not found".

Removing the firebase package from the project's **Swift Packages** section disappeared the error for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the Xcode Report navigator. It clearly listed the problem I was having.

Comment: @JeffreyFulton Glad I could help :]